# limit the growth of a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

Is it possible to limit the `vector.max_size()` in order to limit the growth of a vector?

If not, is having a function to watch the `vector.capacity()` to ensure it doesn't go over a determined amount a viable substitute?

Comment: What is it supposed to do in the case one call `push_back` or `insert` or `assign` or `operator=` and *overshoots* the intended maximum capacity ? Truncate ? Throw ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of. You can write a custom allocator and use it in a `std::vector` (the second template argument of the vector). The allocator needs to satisfy [these requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator). However, doing this properly isn't simple. And your `vector` wouldn't just ignore `push_back` after the max size was met, it would throw.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. But you can define your own subclass of vector (or create completely new vector implementation of your own) which will permit to enforce this requirement if you really want to.

Comment: Inheriting from `std::vector` is a bad suggestion.

Comment: not sure why it is so bad, but he can implement it completely from scratch

Comment: It's a bad idea because `std::vector` wasn't designed to be inherited from. `max_size` isn't virtual, and neither is the destructor. Any access through the `std::vector` interface is going to give unexpected results.

Comment: you could write a new container satisfying `vector`s requirements and internally implemented using a `std::vector`.